# Cannot modify the instance class because there are no instances of the requested class available in the current instance's availability zone

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, cloud, rds

I am trying to upgrade by Amazon RDS Sql Server from an M3.Large to an M4.Large and I am receiving this message "Cannot modify the instance class because there are no instances of the requested class available in the current instance's availability zone. Please try your request again at a later time. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InsufficientDBInstanceCapacity; Request ID: 12cb0aa8-e4ec-11e6-b27f-e722972ee738)"

I have switched it from classic to using the new VPC I have created as well.  Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Which region? Not all instance types are available in all regions.

Comment: @jarmod US EAST (N. Virginia) with availablity zone us-east-1c

Comment: also having this issue, the RDS instance I have is m1.small, created in 2015, stuck in us-east-1d, can't upgrade or change type... painful

Answer (score 2):

Good to have `aws cli` installed
because there is much easier to preview your options

for example by:

```
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options ...
```

check `help` for this subcommand to adjust parameters to your database.

An example showing AZ:

```
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine MySQL --engine-version 8.0.21 --db-instance-class db.m6g.xlarge --query 'OrderableDBInstanceOptions[].AvailabilityZones'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBInstance.html

You're trying to request an m4.large but AWS is unable to provision as it's not available with them. You can raise a ticket with them and I'm sure it will be taken care of soon. [You can request a service limit raise]